# What can I do if my Steam client gets clogged with nearly-complete downloads?

Tags: steam, technical-issues

This has already happened to me several times, and I find it rather annoying. I'll be downloading some game on steam, and once a few single MBs remain do be downloaded, the download will suddenly hang, perhaps downloading a few bytes here and there.

This issue may be related to heavy load on steam's servers (recent bundles, and holidays, probably caused a load spike), so there may be nothing to do other than wait patiently.

Still, I was downloading the last few MBs of *Really Big Sky* for three whole days and if there's anything active I can do to work around this issue, that would be great.

Comment: This sometimes happens to me, even without ongoing large sales (and related Steam overload) and with only a few things in the download queue.

Answer (score 2):

What I do is cancel all downloads and just enable one at a time. This happened when I bought some large bundles in sales. It seems to work.

I don't know whether it is related to load, or whether something just gets borked when you have a large number of downloads at once.

Comment: This is what I usually do, but sadly it didn't help me at all this time around.

Answer (score 2):

My problem sounds similar to yours. What I do is pause all of the downloads, then I click "Play" on one of them. This usually kicks off a separate download window for that game. Usually, this will lead to a consistent and completed download.